# Since Ventura: iCal alerts set for a time when iMac is off don't show up when iMac turned on

Tags: imac, calendar

I have many iCal events set to begin at 6.30AM to 7.30AM. I don't turn on my iMacs till 6.35AM/6.40AM. None of the 6.30AM to 7.30AM alerts show up anymore. They did before the Ventura upgrade.

I don't use Focus or Do Not Disturb and all settings for both are turned off.

Ventura 13.2.1